# Choose n distinct elements from a vector with probability inverse-proportional to their index

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a vector and a certain number of elements n, I'm looking for a way to choose n distinct elements from a vector with probability inverse-proportional to their index.

Example:

```
std::vector v = {0, 1, 2, ... 998, 999};
n = 10;
```

A potential set of chosen indices may be:

```
{50, 200, 350, 500, 600, 700, 800, 850, 900, 950}
```

Notes:

- The chosen indices need to be consistent between invocations.
- The same index cannot be chosen twice in the same invocation result.
- The density of indices from the beginning of the vector must be proportional to the density of indices from the end of the vector. I.e. the result {990 ... 999} is invalid for the given example.
- I'd prefer to use as much code as I can from the standard library rather than having to implement by myself.
- I may prefer a simple and working but less efficient solution over a complicated and efficient solution.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *The chosen indices need to be consistent between invocations* ? In a given invocation, must all indices be distinct?

Comment: In a given invocation, they must all be distinct. I'll make it clear in the post.
What I meant is that for every invocation, the chosen indices must be identical.

Comment: *"with probability inverse-proportional to their index"*. Inverse of index 0 is infinity... Inverse of index 1 is 1. Can you clarify you weight/distribution. Chose 2 between `{a, b, c}`, leads to `{a, b}`, `{a, c}`, `{b, c}`, which are their probabilies?

Comment: Thanks. I added a clarification:
"The density of indices from the beginning of the vector must be proportional to the density of indices from the end of the vector. I.e. the result {990 ... 999} is invalid for the given example."

Comment: *"{990 ... 999} is invalid"*. Invalid or improbable? Not sure you know exactly what you want :) Probability has several pitfalls.

Comment: Sure, improbable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This paper](http://utopia.duth.gr/%7Epefraimi/research/data/2007EncOfAlg.pdf) describes a weighted random sampling method. Below is a C++ implementation.

This is assigning a weight of `1 / index` for a 1-based indexing of your data

```
namespace views = std::ranges::views;

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // or whichever URBG you want
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0, 1);

std::vector<std::pair<double, std::size_t>> weighted_indexes;
weighted_indexes.reserve(v.size());
for (auto i : views::iota(0u, v.size())) {
    auto k = std::pow(dist(gen), i + 1);
    weighted_indexes.emplace_back(k, i);
}
std::sort(weighted_indexes.begin(), weighted_indexes.end());

auto indexes = weighted_indexes | views::take(n) | views::values;
auto selected_values = indexes | views::transform([&v](std::size_t i){ return v[i]; });
```